Spring Boot why always return json when error?
When error, spring return json instead of redirect error page
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Required parameter 'id' is not present.","instance":"/works/detail.html"}

How to redirect to error page when error.

You probably have @ControllerAdvice and/or @ExceptionHandlers.
